# In TFS what is the difference between a workspace and local path mapping?

Tags: tfs, mapping, workspace

I'm learning Team Foundation Server 2015.

I am attempting to set up a repository I have created with code from a local folder.

I created a workspace to connect my repository name with a path on my local machine. While this populated my solution explorer I see in source control explorer my local path says - Not mapped.

if I set a mapping it says this already exists in my workspace.

this also prevents me from adding items to the folder or getting the latest version, both require a mapping.

So do I just need to remove my workspace mapping and set a mapping to a local path within Source Control Explorer instead?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you didn't select the workspace you created. You need to select the workspace you have created for your project:

[image]

Check more information at website: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/create-work-workspaces

Comment: ok thanks now I don't seem to have a version control connection if I right click on a file I don't see any of the source control options to check out etc or simply editing a file doesn't check it out and show the little tick by it...

Comment: You need to click "Get latest Version" in source control explorer .

Comment: yes I do that but get message all files are up to date no files downloaded... force an update.. I then use advanced... get specific version... checkboxes ticked but still no joy with source control options... its like there is no link between TFS code and my local code

Comment: Have you connected to TFS? Could you share your screeshot?

Comment: at the solution level I right click and get the option to add to source control and get the message - The item 'demomvcapp.sln' is already under source control at the selected location. If you are trying to rebind a project that you have already added to source control outside Microsoft Visual Studio, you should use the Change Source Control command. If you are adding this project for the first time, you should either choose a different server folder for the project or move the existing project to a different server folder.

Comment: yes connected I see my tfs url in team explorer and my workspace and under team I see the disconnect from tfs option

Comment: tried deleting my code on the tfs server but get a conflict error saying there are pending changes to the items but pending changes in my work area shows nothing. I think ill delete the whole tfs repository and start again from scratch

Comment: It seems you didn't check in the entire solution into TFS. Try go to VS File--Source Control--Advanced--Change Source Control, to unbind your project. Then try to add your entire solution into TFS.

Comment: how do I add my solution to tfs? I create a workspace mapping my repository to my local drive, I select my workspace click on the soln file and see my files in my solution explorer, I then add solution to source control and check in all my files but they are greyed out on the source control explorer and local path says not mapped if I click on this and set a mapping it says its already set in a workspace.... whats the step by step process to simply set up my local project in TFS repository after I have created both?

Comment: I suggest you read this article first: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/set-up-team-foundation-version-control-your-dev-machine

Comment: ok I followed these steps I still don't get a local path showing as mapped in source control explorer I guess this doesn't matter if a workspace mapping has been set? now I cant seem to work in the Work Items area of team explorer, an error appears - TF26193: The team project e3c0d02b-3912-4494-8f1d-8509cca151ca does not exist. Check the team project name and try again.

Comment: I suggest you open new cases and close this one. Also, you can attach screenshot of your error so that others can better understand your issue.